# Regex remove content before >

Tags: regex, json

Trying to create a Regex that removes ABC before a >. For example.

```
Agencies > Freelancers > Driving Instructors
```

Anything before > is removed. Leaving only Driving Instrucor.

So far I can remove non-alphanumeric

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]
```

I also tried

```
.*?(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9 -])
```

But that only Removes Agencies.

The point of this is,

To first get the first word.

Agencies.

Store that into a json object.
Then, using .match grab any other item that is preceded with "Agencies" as its children.

Thereby I should have this.

```
{"Agencies":[
   {"link":"Freelancers "}, 
   {"link":"Driving Instructors"},
]}
```

I'm not concerned about the jSon, but I need to iterate through first.

thank you.

Comment: To get everything up to and including the last `> `, use `/^.+> /`. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hU3zZ4/1)

Answer (score 2):

Which language? In php, maybe with "explode" you have enough:

```
<?
$string = "Agencies > Freelancers > Driving Instructors";
$exploded = explode(">",$string);
$key = trim(array_shift($exploded));
$array = array($key=>array());
foreach($exploded as $subitem)
{
        $array[$key][] = array("link"=>$subitem);
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Using javascript could be something like this:

```
var string = "Agencies > Freelancers > Driving Instructors";
var exploded = string.split(">");
var key = exploded[0].trim();
var values = new Array();
for(i=1;i<exploded.length;i++)
{
    values.push({link:exploded[i].trim()});
}
var json = "{\"" + key + "\": " + JSON.stringify(values) +"}";
```

Comment: Using jquery to create a json object

Comment: But that does make sense, and I actually could do that.

Comment: I've added the js version, just in case it is useful for you :)